# How to change specific value node in web.config through xmlpoke?

Tags: .net, build, nant

I am using Nant for build process. I need to change my `web.config` file to set end point address.
My web.config file contains 5 endpoint address and I need to change endpoint address of those node which name is like "**service1**"

```
<endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpContextBinding"

 bindingConfiguration="WSHttpContextBinding_Iservice1" contract="xyz" name="**service1**">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a target that calls [xmlpoke](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/0.91/help/tasks/xmlpoke.html)

Sample code:

```
<xmlpoke
file="Web.config"
xpath="/configuration/system.ServiceModel/services/service/endpoint[@name = 'service1']/@address"
value="127.0.0.1:8080" />
```